# Getting error Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Wx/Wx.so' for module Wx

Tags: perl, wxwidgets, cpan, wxperl

I couldn't download Wx properly using cpan and kept getting an error so I tried to force-install it, now, when running:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Wx;
```

I get the following error:

```
Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Wx/Wx.so' for module Wx: libenchant.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 193.
 at test.pl line 3.
Compilation failed in require at test.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 3.
```

Edit: I finally got it to work! First I downloaded libenchant1c2a.deb and converted it into a .txz using deb2tgz, extracted it and placed the files inside in usr/lib usr/lib64 and usr/share after that I just followed Håkon Hægland's instructions and it worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: What was the error when you tried to install `Wx` without --force?

Comment: I didn't copy the error, but it was something quite similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775094/why-does-cpan-install-fail-when-installing-scrappy though, it didn't have anything else past the "7" shown in that error

Comment: What version of Perl are you using, what OS are you on, and which command did you run to install `Wx` ?

Comment: I tried to install [Wx](https://metacpan.org/pod/Wx) from source on Ubuntu 21.04 with perl version 5.32.0. I first installed the wxWidgets libraries (version 3.0.2 from  http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/wxwindows/wxWidgets-3.0.2.tar.bz2) by installing [Alien::wxWidgets](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::wxWidgets) from source. Then, I was able to compile `Wx` (i.e. running `perl Makefile.PL; make`) from source, but when running `make test` one test failed: [ext/xrc/t/01_load.t](https://metacpan.org/release/MDOOTSON/Wx-0.9932/source/ext/xrc/t/01_load.t). This test gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: It's rather strange that it fails because of failing to find `libenchant.so` because this is not something used by wx itself, but installing it from the corresponding package might be enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Re "*so I tried to force-install it*", So you forced the installation of a module that didn't work, and and now you're asking why the installed version doesn't work?

Comment: The error informs you that module `DynaLoader.pm` is looking for library `libenchant.so.1` which it can not find (perhaps it is missing in your system). You need to install a package which provides `libenchant.so.1`. A quick look at [debian packages](https://packages.debian.org/) reveals that this library belongs to `libenchant1c2a` package. Now type following command `apt-get install libenchant1c2a` to install missing library.

Comment: Note: forcing package installation often could lead to situation similar to described in the message. Installation provides an error which gives a clue what is missing and required to make the module function properly. Forced installation will not install missing piece, you should look for solution to install missing piece and only then try to reinstall module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install [Wx](https://metacpan.org/pod/Wx) from source on Ubuntu 21.04 with perl version 5.32.0. I first installed the wxWidgets libraries (version 3.0.2 from prdownloads.sourceforge.net/wxwindows/wxWidgets-3.0.2.tar.bz2) by installing [Alien::wxWidgets](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::wxWidgets) from source:

```
$ wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/M/MD/MDOOTSON/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf Alien-wxWidgets-0.69.tar.gz
$ cd Alien-wxWidgets-0.69.tar.gz
$ perl Makefile.PL 
 perl Makefile.PL 
# running Build.PL 
Do you want to fetch and build wxWidgets from sources? [no ]yes
Which wxWidgets version? (2.8.10, 2.8.11, 2.8.12, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.9.4, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2) [3.0.2 ]
3.0.2 
Which archive type? [tar.bz2 ]
tar.bz2 
Do you want to include OpenGL support [no ]
no 
Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Alien-wxWidgets' version '0.69'

$ make
[...]
/home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/bk-deps g++ -c -o gldll_glx11.o -I./.pch/wxprec_gldll -D__WXGTK__      -DWXBUILDING      -I../src/regex  -DWXUSINGDLL -DWXMAKINGDLL_GL -fPIC -DPIC -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0 -I../include -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -DWX_PRECOMP -pthread -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-unix-print-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden ../src/unix/glx11.cpp
g++ -shared -fPIC -o /home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/lib/libwx_gtk2u_gl-3.0.so.0.2.0  gldll_glcmn.o gldll_gtk_glcanvas.o gldll_glx11.o    -L/home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/lib   -Wl,-soname,libwx_gtk2u_gl-3.0.so.0  -pthread         -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lharfbuzz -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0 -lX11 -lSM -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lharfbuzz -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lpng -lz -ljpeg -ltiff  -lwxregexu-3.0  -pthread   -Wl,--version-script,/home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/version-script -lz -ldl -lm  -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.0 -lwx_baseu-3.0  -lGL -lGLU -lz -ldl -lm
(cd /home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/lib/; rm -f libwx_gtk2u_gl-3.0.so libwx_gtk2u_gl-3.0.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk2u_gl-3.0.so.0.2.0 libwx_gtk2u_gl-3.0.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk2u_gl-3.0.so.0 libwx_gtk2u_gl-3.0.so)
(if test -f utils/wxrc/Makefile ; then cd utils/wxrc && make all ; fi)
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/utils/wxrc'
/home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/bk-deps g++ -c -o wxrc_wxrc.o -D__WXGTK__      -I../../../utils/wxrc -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0 -I../../../include -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -DWX_PRECOMP -pthread -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-unix-print-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden ../../../utils/wxrc/wxrc.cpp
g++ -o wxrc wxrc_wxrc.o    -L/home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/lib  -pthread     -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0 -lexpat -lwx_baseu-3.0     -lwxregexu-3.0  -pthread   -Wl,--version-script,/home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/version-script -lz -ldl -lm  -lz -ldl -lm
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/utils/wxrc'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld'

$ make test
/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/perl Build --makefile_env_macros 1 test
t/01_load.t .......... ok   
t/zy_pod_coverage.t .. ok   
t/zz_pod.t ........... ok     
All tests successful.
Files=3, Tests=15,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr  0.00 sys +  0.25 cusr  0.05 csys =  0.31 CPU)
Result: PASS

$ make install
/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/perl Build --makefile_env_macros 1 install
Building Alien-wxWidgets
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld'
(if test -f utils/wxrc/Makefile ; then cd utils/wxrc && make all ; fi)
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/utils/wxrc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/utils/wxrc'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld'
Files found in blib/arch: installing files in blib/lib into architecture dependent library tree
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld'
mkdir -p /home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux/Alien/wxWidgets/gtk_3_0_2_uni/lib
/bin/install -c -m 644 /home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/lib/libwx_baseu-3.0.so /home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux/Alien/wxWidgets/gtk_3_0_2_uni/lib
/bin/install -c /home/hakon/test/perl/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/lib/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0.2.0 /home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux/Alien/wxWidgets/gtk_3_0_2_uni/lib
(cd /home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux/Alien/wxWidgets/gtk_3_0_2_uni/lib ; rm -f libwx_baseu-3.0.so libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0; ln -s libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0.2.0 libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0; ln -s libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0 libwx_baseu-3.0.so)
[...]
done
 
 ------------------------------------------------------
 
 The installation of wxWidgets is finished.  On certain
 platforms (e.g. Linux) you'll now have to run ldconfig
 if you installed a shared library and also modify the
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH (or equivalent) environment variable.
 
 wxWidgets comes with no guarantees and doesn't claim
 to be suitable for any purpose.
 
 Read the wxWindows Licence on licencing conditions.
 
 ------------------------------------------------------
```

Then, I was able to compile `Wx`:

```
$ wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/M/MD/MDOOTSON/Wx-0.9932.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf Wx-0.9932.tar.gz
$ cd Wx-0.9932
$ perl Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
'WX' is not a known MakeMaker parameter name.
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lwx_gtk2u_webview-3.0
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lwx_gtk2u_media-3.0
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Wx
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

======================================================================
For installation instructions and further help please see
docs/INSTALL.pod

For command line switches help use:
perl Makefile.PL --help
======================================================================

$ make
[...]
g++ -pthread   -c -I. -I.. -I/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux/Alien/wxWidgets/gtk_3_0_2_uni/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0 -I/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux/Alien/wxWidgets/gtk_3_0_2_uni/include/wx-3.0  -I. -I. -I/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux/Alien/wxWidgets/gtk_3_0_2_uni/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0 -I/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux/Alien/wxWidgets/gtk_3_0_2_uni/include/wx-3.0   -I. -I../.. -I/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux/Alien/wxWidgets/gtk_3_0_2_uni/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0 -I/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux/Alien/wxWidgets/gtk_3_0_2_uni/include/wx-3.0  -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.01\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.01\" -fPIC "-I/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/5.32.0/x86_64-linux/CORE" -DWXPL_EXT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__   -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__    -DWXPL_EXT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__   XRC.c
rm -f ../../blib/arch/auto/Wx/XRC/XRC.so
LD_RUN_PATH="/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux/Alien/wxWidgets/gtk_3_0_2_uni/lib" g++    -shared -O2  -fstack-protector-strong  XRC.o  -o ../../blib/arch/auto/Wx/XRC/XRC.so  \
   -L/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux/Alien/wxWidgets/gtk_3_0_2_uni/lib -lpthread -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.0 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.0 -lwx_baseu-3.0   \

[...]
```

But running the tests failed initially. For some reason the embedded [run path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) in the Perl generated shared objects did not help the dynamic loader to find the location of the wx libraries. So I needed to explicitly set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
$ perl -MAlien::wxWidgets -E 'say Alien::wxWidgets->prefix'
/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux/Alien/wxWidgets/gtk_3_0_2_uni
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux/Alien/wxWidgets/gtk_3_0_2_uni/lib make test

"/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- DataView.bs ../../blib/arch/auto/Wx/DataView/DataView.bs 644
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, '../../blib/lib', '../../blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/01_load.t ......... ok   
t/02_inheritance.t .. ok    
t/03_threads.t ...... skipped: no threads
t/08_ovl_func.t ..... ok     
All tests successful.
Files=4, Tests=25,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.00 sys +  0.25 cusr  0.03 csys =  0.30 CPU)
Result: PASS
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/hakon/test/perl/Wx-0.9932/ext/dataview'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/hakon/test/perl/Wx-0.9932/ext/docview'
"/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- DocView.bs ../../blib/arch/auto/Wx/DocView/DocView.bs 644
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, '../../blib/lib', '../../blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/01_load.t ......... ok   
t/02_inheritance.t .. ok    
[...]
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/hakon/test/perl/Wx-0.9932/ext/pperl/carp'
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, '../../../blib/lib', '../../../blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/01_load.t .. ok   
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr  0.01 sys +  0.08 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.10 CPU)
Result: PASS
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/hakon/test/perl/Wx-0.9932/ext/pperl/carp'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/hakon/test/perl/Wx-0.9932/ext/pperl/textval'
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, '../../../blib/lib', '../../../blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/01_load.t .. ok   
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr  0.00 sys +  0.07 cusr  0.02 csys =  0.10 CPU)
Result: PASS
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/hakon/test/perl/Wx-0.9932/ext/pperl/textval'
No tests defined for Wx::Perl extension.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/hakon/test/perl/Wx-0.9932/ext/pperl'
No tests defined for Wx extension.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hakon/test/perl/Wx-0.9932/ext'
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/01_load.t ........... ok   
t/02_inheritance.t .... ok     
t/03_event.t .......... ok     
t/04_userdata.t ....... ok     
t/05_timer.t .......... ok   
t/06_loadxpm.t ........ ok   
t/07_overload.t ....... ok       
t/08_ovl_func.t ....... ok       
t/09_create_delete.t .. ok   
t/10_oor.t ............ ok     
t/11_twostage.t ....... ok   
t/12_pod.t ............ skipped: Author tests
t/13_nbksizer.t ....... ok   
t/14_eh_die.t ......... ok   
t/15_threads.t ........ skipped: no threads
t/16_stream.t ......... ok   
t/17_thread_evt.t ..... skipped: no threads
t/18_unicode.t ........ ok     
t/19_overlay.t ........ ok   
t/20_ctx_threads.t .... skipped: no threads
t/21_locale.t ......... ok   
t/22_interface.t ...... ok   
t/zz_distrib.t ........ skipped: Author tests
All tests successful.

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/04_userdata.t     (Wstat: 0 Tests: 65 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   25, 49, 57
Files=23, Tests=770,  6 wallclock secs ( 0.12 usr  0.02 sys +  1.82 cusr  0.52 csys =  2.48 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

And then I could install it:

```
$ make install
$ perl -E 'use Wx; say "It works"'
It works
```

Comment: Definition of variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` indicates that linker does not know how to find specified library. The situation can be remedied by modifying `/etc/ld.so.conf` and re-run [ldconfig](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html).